# Using mockup-patterns in faceted-views in Plone 5

Tags: javascript, plone-5.x

When I use any mockup-pattern like `<span class="pat-moment">2016-07-30T15:10:00</span>` in a `faceted:view` (a custom view for eea.facetednavigation) the pattern is not working at all since the content is injected with javascript.

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/35699974/637399 @ebrehault wrote that Patterns are initialized at load time and if the DOM changes and contains new elements, you need to call `Registry.scan($('#content-core'))` where `Registry` is `pat-registry` and `#content-core` the injected part of the page.

How do I do that in the context of eea.facetednavigation (https://github.com/eea/eea.facetednavigation)? It uses a event-system (see https://github.com/eea/eea.facetednavigation/blob/master/eea/facetednavigation/browser/javascript/view.js). How do I listen to one of these events, which one do I need and how do I then call the scan?

Comment: I suspect you want to use MutationObserver to watch the changes made by eea.facetednavigation (sorry, not MSIE < 11 support). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

For older MSIE, you may need use a polyfill that uses setInterval polling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind to the eea's AJAX_QUERY_SUCCESS event:

```
$(Faceted.Events).bind(Faceted.Events.AJAX_QUERY_SUCCESS, function() {
        Registry.scan($('#content-core'));
});
```

Note: when you said:

> and #content-core the injected part of the page.

that's not accurate, it is not specifically the injection target (by the way there is not always injection when you use patterns, in your very case the injection is managed by eea.faceted, which is not a pattern). You can re-scan any part of the DOM, you just need to  make sure the part you re-scan contains the patterns you want to activate (`body` would be just fine for instance).

Comment: Thanks, that works great! I'm so used to python that I constantly wonder how ``$(Faceted.Events)`` works without imports :-)

Answer (score 1):

For Plone 5: I registered the code snippet below as a resource in the *registry.xml* in my addon, included it in the bundles addon in my *registry.xml* and rebuild my addons bundle using the *./bin/plone-compile-resources* script.

```
define([
    'pat-registry'
], function(Registry) {
  'use strict';
    $(Faceted.Events).bind(Faceted.Events.AJAX_QUERY_SUCCESS, function() {
      Registry.scan($('#content-core'));
    });
});
```